# Binding Checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, checkboxlist

I need a simple way to bind the checkboxlist in `asp.net /C#`.

I am pulling 3 columns from database Id, Name and IsActive. Id and Name i think will be clear by its name. And IsActive will be used to show checked and unchecked box. I just want to know, **can I bind the child check box values with IsActive while data binding?**

E.g.

```
cbxlFeatures.DataSource = dt;
cbxlFeatures.DataValueField = "Id";
cbxlFeatures.DataTextField = "Name"; // something similar to this
cbxlFeatures.SomePropert= "IsActive";
cbxlFeatures.DataBind();
```

I know the conventional way to iterate through the items and data columns and compare and put checks.
I need some easy and optimized way...

Thanks

Comment: @humpty dumpty : thanks for formatting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try manually populating your checkboxlist instead,  I believe the code below would do the trick for you.

```
private void PopulateCheckBoxList( List<MyClass> myClassList )
{
    foreach ( MyClass m in myClassList )
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem( m.Name, m.Id.ToString() );
        item.Selected = m.IsActive;
        cbxlFeatures.Items.Add( item );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way of doing this with a property of CheckBoxList. Iterating through the items seems that it may be the solution.