# C# asp.net Create multiple check box dynamically with value of mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i am trying to create multiple check box with the value of mysql database fetched rows say for me if i have 10 rows in DB i need 10 check box to be created dynamically in a div.

am not sure how to do that but i have done a slimier code which add's a "," after each fetch.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStrings"].ConnectionString;


using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
{

    using (MySqlCommand MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FatherFullName FROM xxxxxx where sssss='xxxxx'", con))
    {
        MySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader MySqlDataReader = MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        var list = new List<string>();
        while (MySqlDataReader.Read())
        {

            string name = MySqlDataReader["FatherFullName"].ToString();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                list.Add(name);



        }
        con.Close();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest use asp.net CheckBoxList Control, Suppose its name is CheckBoxList1 then Declare Datatable and get the data to be bind in that datatables Object

```
using (MySqlCommand MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FatherFullName FROM xxxxxx where sssss='xxxxx'", con))
    {
        MySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = MySqlCommand.ExecuteTable();
        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
           CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dt;
           CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Title";
           CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "ArticleID";
           CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
        }

                   con.Close();   

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have a question where will that all check box will be projected and one more thing is  `DataTable dt = MySqlCommand.ExecuteTable();` gives `ExecuteTable are not expected`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11781490/3583859 use this answer for binding checkboxlist from list.